# How to move an object to the top of an array with AngularFire?

Tags: javascript, firebase, angularfire

I am trying to move an object to the top of an array with AngularFire.

My array in Firebase is simmilar to this:

```
$scope.todos = [
    {title:"Work out", timetag:"new Date()", done: false },
    {title:"Home work", timetag:"new Date()", done: false }
];
```

I created a function that uses vanilla javascript that stores the object to a variable. The function deletes the object from the array that you want to move up to the beginning of the array. The function then replaces the object you stored to a variable to the beginning of the array.

Here is the code I have:

```
$scope.moveUpPriority = function($index){
    var toMove = $scope.todos[$index];
    delete $scope.todos[$index];
    $scope.todos.splice(0,0, toMove);
    $scope.todos.$save();
  };
```

This code snippet is almost completely working the way I want. When I run this on my todo list, It moves the todo task up the array. However when I refresh the page, it doesn't stick.

What are the appropriate AngularFire Methods to completely save or set this type of javascript code to my Firebase Backend?

Comment: Is the template you are rendering using some kind of orderBy expression? If yes, the order the todo-s are in is irrelevent since angular will order them by the specific property.

Comment: The template is using a "high priority" button, that appears with ng-show/ng-hide when your mouse hovers over the task. So the code snippet above executes when you click the "high priority" button with ng-click.

Answer (score 0):

To preserve the order of the TODOs you could add a property named for example `priority`.

When a TODO is dragged/moved up the priority list you should then re-set the priority values of the TODOs save them and order them by that property in your template.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so array methods like  splice(), push(), pop(), shift(), unshift(), and reverse() will cause the Firebase Array to break.

- So my work around was to edit/change the array with standard Javascript Array methods.

  Then I store a copy of the local(edited)state array to a variable.

  Then I delete the Firebase array.

  Then I pushed the keys of the local array to Firebase.

---

Here is the code below:

```
$scope.moveUpPriority = function($index){
    var toMove = $scope.todos[$index]; //save copy of $index todo

   $scope.todos.splice($index,1); //removes item at $index 
   $scope.todos.splice(0,0, toMove); //adds item toMove to the start of array

   var backup = $scope.todos; //copy back up array


   for(var b = 0; b<= $scope.todos.length; b++){
    $scope.todos.$remove($scope.todos[b]); //remove items from array
   }

   for(var i = 0; i<= backup.length; i++){
    $scope.todos.$add(backup[i]); // add items from back up array
   }
 };
```